# What address malloc and calloc returns?

Tags: heap-memory

Is the `malloc` or `calloc` returns pointer which specifies the exact location of data to be stored?

Answer (score 0):

[See here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html)

> The malloc() and calloc() functions return a pointer to the allocated
>          memory, which is suitably aligned for any built-in type.  On error,
>          these functions return NULL.  NULL may also be returned by a
>          successful call to malloc() with a size of zero, or by a successful
>          call to calloc() with nmemb or size equal to zero.

It returns an address which is valid in the current process.